# Getting error when try to create meeting on exchange calendar through exchange api

Tags: exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I am using EWS Managed exchange api in c#
I am getting below error when i am try to create meeting on default calendar (**Calendar**).

**Cannot create a calendar item in a non-calendar folder.**

here is my code :

Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);

appointment.Subject = "Test meeting";

appointment.Body = "Test Connection meeting";

appointment.Start = meetingStartTime;

appointment.End = meetingEndTime;

appointment.Sensitivity = Sensitivity.Normal;

```
            appointment.Save(calendarId, SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
```

**Note :** I am fetching the calendar by calendar name.
As below

SearchFilter sfSearchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(**FolderSchema.DisplayName, "Calendar"**);

Please revert as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most certainly the error is where you fetch the `SearchResult`.

A workaround would be to just call

```
appointment.Save(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
```

This calls for the default calendar folder without the need to search it first.